# CSS properties are not being inherited?

Tags: html, css

I have the following piece of code:

```
<div style='width:50%;background:yellow;margin:0 auto;padding:20px;font-family:Calibri;'>
    Parent div
    <div style='background:lime;'>
      Child div
    </div>
</div>
```

Here the style `font-family:Calibri;` is *automatically inherited* in the child-div, whereas the other styles remain ***bequeathed*** (un-inherited).

Here's a [**DEMO**](http://jsbin.com/yojatenihu/1/edit?html,output).

[**DEMO after defining same padding for child-div**](http://jsbin.com/gatazulari/1/edit?html,output).

As you can see the result is **NOT** same.

Why is it so? Are there any specific styles which are inherited? If so, what are they?

Comment: I see all of the styles inherited... the background is specifically called to go to lime, but the padding, margin, width... all pass down to the child. Not sure what you are asking...

Comment: try adding 'padding:20px' to the child div, you'll see the difference :)

check this: http://jsbin.com/gatazulari/1/edit?html,output

Comment: Here you go http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/propidx.html. Fifth column.

Comment: Some properties are inherited, others are not. For instance, it makes no sense to inherit padding. Basic CSS. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/inheritance, which refers to it as a "basic concept".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some properties are inherited, and some aren't.

- [`width`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#the-width-property). Inherited: no
- [`background`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/colors.html#background-properties). Inherited: no
- [`margin`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#margin-properties).  Inherited: no
- [`padding`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#padding-properties).  Inherited: no
- [`font-family`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/fonts.html#font-family-prop).  Inherited: yes

If you want some element to inherit the value of a non-inheritable property from its parent, you can use [`inherit` value](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#value-def-inherit).

---

I suggest reading [Inheritance](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#inheritance) section of the spec:

> Some values are inherited by the children of an element in the document tree, as described above. Each property defines whether it is inherited or not.
>
> When inheritance occurs, elements inherit computed values. The computed value from the parent element becomes both the specified value and the computed value on the child.
>
> Each property may also have a cascaded value of 'inherit', which means that, for a given element, the property takes the same specified value as the property for the element's parent. The 'inherit' value can be used to enforce inheritance of values, and it can also be used on properties that are not normally inherited.